# How to claim a premium name?

Tags: cleos, premium, claim, namespace

what is the `cleos` command to claim a **premium** name after winning the bid?
is it even possible to claim it via `cleos` command line tool? searching through its parameters there's not much that leads to claiming. also looking at the online documentation for cleos utility it is not explained there either.

thank you

Comment: `cleos system newaccount <premium-name> -p <winning-account>`?

Comment: cleos system newaccount --buy-ram-kbtes 4 --stake-net "0.1 EOS" --stake-cpu "0.1 EOS" creator newaccount ownerkey activekey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems this is the command, you have to basically create the account:

```
$ cleos system newaccount --buy-ram-kbtes 4 --stake-net "0.1 EOS" --stake-cpu "0.1 EOS" creator newaccount ownerkey activekey
```

Answer (score 1):

If you win the bid for a premium name, you have the right to 
to claim it, i.e. the right to create the premium name and link it to a new public key.

I tried to create the premium name on several popular EOS sites: eosauthority, eosx, eostoolkit...However, these sites do not allow the creation of a new account name with less than the default 12 characters.

Also, the alternative route to use a CLEOS command, is complex, because it requires the installation of the full EOSIO platform.

My solution:

-Download the lightweight multiplatform command line tool for interaction with the EOS blockchain; EOSC by EOSCanada. This program enables you to connect to the EOS mainnet from your cmd in Windows.

-Create a local wallet and store the creator keys:

> eosc vault create --import [CREATOR PUBLIC KEY]

-Create the premium name:

> eosc system newaccount [CREATOR ACCOUNT NAME] [PREMIUM ACCOUNT NAME] --auth-key [PREMIUM ACCOUNT PUBLIC KEY, make sure you are in possession of related private key!] --stake-cpu "0.1" --stake-net "0.1"

I am now the proud owner of the premium name .nl :-)
Robert